# Update нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа

Tags: sql, foreign-key

Здраствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, не могу задать внешний ключ.

Схема простая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица master и таблица employer_img, хранящая изображение.
Команда тоже простая

```
alter table master
    add constraint master_img_fk
        foreign key (id_employer_img) references employer_img  (id);
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> INSERT или UPDATE в таблице "master" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "master_img_fk" Подробности: Ключ (id_employer_img)=(1) отсутствует в таблице "employer_img".

Да что не так???

Comment: в таблице master есть запись в которой id_employer_img равен 1, но в таблице employer_img нет записи с таким идентификатором

Comment: *Схема простая* Да ладно... простая. Как Вы намерены обеспечивать строго one-to-one (причём блокировать как one-to-many, так и one-to-zero)?